# Vue3 with ASP.NET MVC: Props not being passed in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vuejs3

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which I've inherited. The most recent new bits of functionality use custom Vue2 components. Each MVC view is effectively a Single Page Application as I understand it. Each view has its own index.js file e.g.

```
import Vue from "vue"
window.Vue = Vue

import Test from '@/components/test'

const vm = new Vue({
    el: "#test",
    components: {
        Test
    },
    data() {
        return {}
    }
})
```

The top level component is a single file component e.g. Test.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Test',
        props: {
            message: {
                type: String,
                default: 'This has not worked'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The MVC view itself looks like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MentorNet.cshtml";
}

<div id="test" v-cloak>
    <test message="This has worked"></test>
</div>
@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/dist/js/test.js")" defer></script>
}
```

The /dist/js/test.js file is created as a result of running Webpack with vue-loader.

With Vue2 this works fine. In this example the text "This has worked" appears when the controller returns the view.

However I'm trying to upgrade to Vue3 and this isn't working. The index.js file now looks like:

```
import { createApp } from "vue"

import Test from '@/views/admin/test'

const app = createApp(Test);
app.mount("#test");
```

The component and the view are the same. The component is displayed but the props are not passed through - the view returns the text "This has not worked".

I've looked at the Vue2 migration guide and can't see any breaking changes that would affect this. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer thanks to a response on the Vue Land Discord channel.

The problem was with the code in the index.js file:

```
const app = createApp(Test);
app.mount("#test");
```

When passing a component with a template/render function to createApp it completely overwrites the content of the mount target, in this case

```
<div id="test">
  <test message="This has worked"></test>
</div>
```

so the

```
<test message="This has worked"></test>
```

isn't used. The correct way to do it is either to pass the props as the second argument of create App:

```
const app = createApp(Test, { 
  message: "This has worked" 
});
```

or, and the way I'm going to be doing it:

```
const app = createApp({
   components: { Test }
});
```